# Alarms not going off during calls

Tags: calls, clock

When I am in a call, whether it be through phone, Skype, hangouts, etc... it mutes all system alarms, except vibration.

I know this is probably intended behavior but is there anyway to reverse this functionality?

I am running Android 7.0 on a Galaxy S7, using the system clock app for alarms

Comment: Probably it is designed that way. You can consider automation. [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) is the automation app I use. Trigger : Call active; Action: volume change > set alarm to desired level

Comment: Re reading the question, you are talking of system alarms so in action above it should be system sounds set to appropriate level

Comment: @beeshyams I'm gonna give this a try and see how it works

Comment: I haven't tested it myself - should work unless it's an Android design constraint that can't be overcome

Comment: Another alternative , if it is only clock that is not ringing is to use a third party alarm clock like [Amdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amdroidalarmclock.amdroid) - by default, unless you change it, it is meant to ring while in call

Comment: Were you able to try it out?